# Exclude div on single page

Tags: php, wordpress

On a Wordpress site my page.php contains a div that I want to exclude from a single article. I've messed around with the is_single function but I can't get it working.

Any good ideas on how I solve this?

Comment: Please provide some code you've made and the desired output.

Comment: for page conditional use is_page() and for single post is_single()
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/
and both post or page use is_is_singular()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Answer (score 1):

If i get you right, you can do:

```
<?php if (!is_single():)  ?>
<div>
//your div here
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @niklas will work. You can also accomplish this by hiding it with CSS. You could do something like this:

```css
.page div.class{
    display:none;
}
```

*Replace `.class` with the class (or ID) of the `div` you want to hide*

Or to hide it on a specific page (or post) you can use the ID class:

```css
.page-id-1 div.class{
    display:none;
}
```

*Replace `1` with the ID of the page where you want to hide the `div`*

You can find more information about the available CSS-classes on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class.